# How to set parameter date + 24 months as date range in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, parameters

I want to filter my matrix in SSRS for the range of 24 months. So if the parameter is set to DATE = 01.01.2016, the table should show all data from 01.01.2016 until 01.12.2017.

For now I was able to set a parameter to a specific month e.g. 01.01.2016. But I couldn't figure out how to implement the date range of 24 months from start date.

The query is quite simple:

```
SELECT     DATE
        , VALUE
FROM table
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can achieve this, depending on which database you are using.
I just tried with MYSQL.

```
SELECT DATE,VALUE
FROM table where DATE>=date_Parameter  and DATE<=DATE_ADD(date_Parameter, INTERVAL 24 MONTH);
```

You just have to take care which database you are using and maybe command changes with it, but core idea remains same.